# Bilinear pairings

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an exercise on bilinear pairings that I can't quite solve.

> Let $K$ be a field, and let $M$, $N$ and $L$ be three $K$-vector spaces. We
> denote by $\operatorname{Bil}(M,N;L)$ the $K$-vector space of bilinear pairings $M \times N \to L$.
>
> 1. Assume that $M$, $N$ and $L$ are finite dimensional. Show that: $$\dim (\operatorname{Bil}(M,N;L)) = \dim(M) \dim(N) \dim(L).$$
> 2. Construct an isomorphism of $K$-vector spaces $\operatorname{Bil}(M,N;L) \cong \operatorname{Bil}(N,M;L)$.
> 3. Let $f:M' \to M$, $g:N' \to N$ and $h : L \to L'$ be $K$-linear maps. Show that there is a $K$-linear map $$\mathcal X : \operatorname{Bil}(M,N;L) \to \operatorname{Bil}(M',N';L')$$ sending a bilinear pairing $\phi(−, −)$ to $h(\phi(f(−), g(−)))$.
> 4. Take $N = M$ and assume that $\operatorname{char}(K) \neq 2$. A bilinear pairing $\phi : M \times M \to L$ is said to be symmetric (resp. alternating) if $\phi(m, m') = \phi(m', m)$ for all $m,m' \in M$ (resp. $\phi(m, m') = −\phi(m', m)$ for all $m,m' \in M$). Show that there is a direct sum decomposition $$\operatorname{Bil}(M,N;L) = \operatorname{Sym}(M;L) \oplus \operatorname{Alt}(M;L)$$ where $\operatorname{Sym}(M;L)$ (resp. $\operatorname{Alt}(M;L)$) is the subspace of all symmetric (resp. alternating) pairings.

I don't really have any solution so far, more just ideas. But I'm struggling trying to write it down correctly. For 2. I have to show that it is an isomorphism, so I have to show that it is a bijective homomorphism.
So for example if we let $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ in $\operatorname{Bil}(M,N;L)$, and $a \in K$  ,then I have to show that $\phi_1 + a\phi_2$ maps to $(\textrm{image of }\phi_1) + a(\textrm{image of }\phi_2)$.

But still, I'm not quite sure how to proceed from this.

Answer (score 1):

The followings are some hints, I suggest you to do the rest by definition of linear map or linear space.

1/ Let $\text{dim}(M)=m, \text{dim}(N)=n,\text{dim}(L)=\ell$, and fix bases $\{ e_i\}$ for $M$, $\{ f_j \}$ for $N$ and $\{g_k \}$ for $L$. You want to check that the following set is a basis for $\text{Bil}(M,N;L)$:
$$\{\phi_{ijk}: i=1,\ldots ,m; \ j= 1,\ldots ,n ; \ k=1,\ldots ,\ell \}$$
where for each $i,j,k$, we define $\phi_{ijk}(e_i,f_j)=g_k$ and $\phi_{ijk}(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

2/ The map $\Phi: \text{Bil}(M,N;L) \to \text{Bil}(N,M;L)$ can be defined as follows: $$\text{for each  } f\in \text{Bil}(M,N;L), \text{  define   } \Phi(f)(x,y):=f(y,x).$$ Its inverse has the same definition $\Psi: \text{Bil}(N,M;L) \to \text{Bil}(M,N;L)$ is defined as: for each $g\in \text{Bil}(N,M;L)$, define $\Psi(g)(x,y):=g(y,x)$. Here, of course you have to check that $\Phi,\Psi$ are linear maps and they are inverse by definition.

3/ This is already very clear what you have to do: check that the map $\mathcal{X} $ defined in the question is linear map by definition.

4/ For each $f\in \text{Bil}(M,M;L)$, for $(x,y)\in M\times M$, you can write $f(x,y)$ as: $$f(x,y)=\dfrac{f(x,y)+f(y,x)}{2} + \dfrac{f(x,y)-f(y,x)}{2}$$
Now show that $g(x,y)=\dfrac{f(x,y)+f(y,x)}{2}$ is a symmetric bilinear pairing and $h(x,y)=\dfrac{f(x,y)-f(y,x)}{2}$ is an alternating bilinear pairing (all by definition). This will give the decomposition $$\text{Bil}(M,M;L)=\text{Sym}(M;L)+\text{Alt}(M;L)$$
The last thing to show is that if $f\in \text{Sym}(M;L)\cap \text{Alt}(M;L)$ then $f=0$. This should be simple since $f(x,y)=f(y,x)=-f(x,y)$, hence, $f(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$.